# Как прослушивать добавление новых элементов в DOM дерево при помощи jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Имеется простая html таблица, в ней содержатся строки с классами по городам.

```
<td>
    <tr class="spb"></tr>
    <tr class="moscow"></tr>
</td>
```

Имеются кнопки, при клике на которые скрываются строки c определённым городом через `display: none;`.

```
// начало кнопка для скрытия всех объявлений по СПБ
$('#hide-moscow').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('tr.moscow').addClass('hide-moscow');
    } else {
        $('tr.moscow').removeClass('hide-moscow');
    }
});
```

Некоторые строки динамически подгружаются через AJAX и добавляются в DOM - дерево, но уже без свойства `display: none;`.

Вопрос: как с помощью JQuery реализовать автоматическое скрытие вновь добавившихся строк (при условии, что кнопка для скрытия нажата)?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил более унифицированную версию. В любом случае - после `ajax` нужно еще раз проверку совершать

JS:

```
$('#hide-moscow').change(function(){
    hideCity('moscow');
});

$('#hide-spb').change(function(){
    hideCity('spb');
});

$.ajax({
    success: function(msg){
        $('table').append('<tr class="moscow"><td>Москва</td></tr>')
        // После успешного ajax и добавления в таблицу новых данных - еще раз вызываем функцию.
        hideCity('moscow');
    }
});

// создаем функцию, которая умеет принимать параметры (город)
function hideCity(city){
    t = $('#hide-'+city);
    if (t.is(':checked')){
        $('tr.'+city).addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('tr.'+city).removeClass('hide');
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
tr.hide {display:none;}
```